# regex: extract segments of a string containing a word, between symbols

Tags: r, regex, string

Hello I have a data frame that looks something like this

```
dataframe <- data_frame(text = c('WAFF, some words to keep, ciao, WOFF hey ;other ;WIFF12',
                                 'WUFF;other stuff to keep;WIFF2;yes yes IGWIFF'))

print(dataframe)
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  text                                                   
  <chr>                                                  
1 WAFF, some words to keep, ciao, WOFF hey ;other ;WIFF12
2 WUFF;other stuff to keep;WIFF2;yes yes IGWIFF
```

I want to extract the segment of the strings containing the word "keep". Note that these segments can be separated from other parts by different symbols for example `,` and `;`.

the final dataset should look something like this.

```
final_dataframe <- data_frame(text = c('some words to keep',
                                 'other stuff to keep'))

print(final_dataframe)
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  text               
  <chr>              
1 some words to keep 
2 other stuff to keep
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: @akrun I'm not so sure akrun, seeing your edits, I mis-read the question, hence the deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `stringr` ...

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>% 
   mutate(text = trimws(str_extract(text, "(?<=[,;]).*keep")))
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  text               
  <chr>              
1 some words to keep 
2 other stuff to keep
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is really akrun's answer, with help from akrun's edits

Answer (score 2):

I've made great use of the positive lookbehind and positive lookahead group constructs -- check this out: https://regex101.com/r/Sc7h8O/1

If you want to assert that the text you're looking for comes after a character/group -- in your first case the apostrophe, use `(?<=')`.

If you want to do the same but match something before `'` then use `(?=')`
And you want to match between 0 and unlimited characters surrounding "keep" so use `.*` on either side, and you wind up with `(?<=').*keep.*(?=')`

I did find in my test that a string like `text =' c('WAFF, some words to keep, ciao, WOFF hey ;other ;WIFF12',` will also match the `c(`, which I didn't intend. But I assume your strings are all captured by pairs of apostrophes.